# how to enlarge an element and show text on clicking

Tags: jquery, css

I had an image as background, and will add an elements over it (Circular points) in certain positions

[image]

How to make this points on clicking, enlarge and show text !?

[image]

If not possible with only `CSS` I wonder if `jQuery` might help.

Here [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xoy5hh7b/)

*CSS*

```
#container {
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
  position: relative;
}
#image {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
#point {
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  z-index: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background: rgba(26, 26, 26, 0.85);
  border: 5px solid #7fcff7;
}
```

*HTML*

```
<div id="container">
<img id="image" src="http://s24.postimg.org/jnd9wc0n9/M7a_Uku_S.png"/>
<p id="point" style="top:15%;left:35%"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: from what i can see you dont enlarge the point but you create a whole new element which has a text on it..is this a show/hide? pls clarify the OP

Comment: @guradio Well! my question is how to make it enlarge on click and show text like seen in image two.

Comment: my suggestion is show/hide since you have the css on the point then easier way is to have a hidden element then just do show/hide

Comment: there was try here [codepen](https://s.codepen.io/scarl3tt/debug/jEBmyG) based on only `css` but seems to be working only on `Chrome` that is why i been thinking about `jquery`

Comment: which browser dont work?

Comment: `Firefox` and `Safari` both works but text not shown up .. however it works perfect on `chrome`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you need like this ?

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
 #container {
   height: 400px;
   width: 400px;
   position: relative;
 }
 #image {
   position: absolute;
   left: 0;
   top: 0;
 }
 #point {
   cursor: pointer;
   outline: none;
   z-index: 0;
   position: absolute;
   width: 20px;
   height: 20px;
   border-radius: 20px;
   background: rgba(26, 26, 26, 0.85);
   border: 5px solid #7fcff7;
 }
    </style>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script>
 
 $(document).ready(function(){
  text1=$("#point").text();
  $("#point").text("")
  $("#point").click(function(){
   $(this).css("width","250px");
   $(this).css("height","200px");
   $(this).css("font-size","20px");
   $(this).css("color","#fff");
   $(this).css("text-align","center");
   $("#point").text(text1)
  });
 });
 </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="container">
<img id="image" src="http://s24.postimg.org/jnd9wc0n9/M7a_Uku_S.png"/>
<p id="point" style="top:15%;left:35%">dsadsad</p>

</div>
   
</body>
</html>
```

For multi points

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
 #container {
   height: 400px;
   width: 400px;
   position: relative;
 }
 #image {
   position: absolute;
   left: 0;
   top: 0;
 }
 .point {
   cursor: pointer;
   outline: none;
   z-index: 0;
   position: absolute;
   width: 20px;
   height: 20px;
   font-size:1px;
   border-radius: 20px;
   background: rgba(26, 26, 26, 0.85);
   border: 5px solid #7fcff7;
   overflow:hidden;
 }
    </style>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script>
 
 $(document).ready(function(){  
  $(".point").click(function(){
   
   $(".point").css("width","20px");
   $(".point").css("height","20px");
   $(".point").css("font-size","1px");
   $(".point").css("color","#000");
   $(".point").css("text-align","center");
   
   $(this).css("width","250px");
   $(this).css("height","200px");
   $(this).css("font-size","20px");
   $(this).css("color","#fff");
   $(this).css("text-align","center");
   
  });
 });
 </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="container">
<img id="image" src="http://s24.postimg.org/jnd9wc0n9/M7a_Uku_S.png"/>
<p class="point" style="top:15%;left:35%">dsadsad</p>
<p class="point" style="top:55%;left:75%">dsadsad</p>

</div>
   
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: this is perfect and helps a lot .. but i wonder what if i want to add another point `<p id="point" style="top:35%;left:55%">Another point</p>`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can achieve it using jquery.

1. Just append a div and make its `display as Hidden`
2. Then, on the click of the circle, get the pageX and pageY value of the click event and apply it on the div

   ```
   $("#point").click(function(e){
       $(".showDiv").slideToggle();
       $(".showDiv").css({
         "top": Number(e.pageY)+"px",
         "left": Number(e.pageX)+"px",
       });
       $(".showDiv").text("PLace Text");
   });
   ```

Here is the [Link](https://jsfiddle.net/xoy5hh7b/2/)

Hope it helps :)

( Updated the code for Toggle effect :D )